# Sum of absolute change per date for particular stock

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe and for each date I want to calculate the sum of absolute change in sales for each individual stock over each date.

Sample df:

```
            Stock      Sales    Data 1
1/1/2012    Amazon    120       0.996691907
1/1/2012    Apple     230       0.084699221
1/1/2012    Microsoft 340       0.141253424
1/1/2012    Google    230       0.506264018
1/2/2012    Amazon    340       0.646633737
1/2/2012    Apple     1250      0.204030887
1/2/2012    Microsoft 850       0.556935133
1/2/2012    Dell      650       0.771751177
1/2/2012    Yahoo     650       0.615222763
1/2/2012    Verizon   1065      0.504410742
1/2/2012    Vodafone  200       0.752335341
1/2/2012    Blackberry 1465     0.693017964
1/2/2012    AT&T      2000      0.262392424
1/3/2012    Apple     1465      0.851841806
1/3/2012    Amazon    1465      0.70635569
1/3/2012    AT&T      700       0.911297224
1/3/2012    Blackberry 235      0.118843588
1/3/2012    Vodafone  500       0.07255267
```

Output df_new would be:

```
1/1/2012    920
1/2/2012    7780
1/3/2012    11050
```

Calculation:

For **1/1/2012** (first date in index), the calculation would just be the sum of Sales for that day (120+230+340+230) = 920

For **1/2/2012** (next date), the calculation would be the absolute change in sales for a particular stock during the date change. 
Eg, Amazon, Apple and Microsoft are already in the first date and the rest of the stocks are new so the sum of absolute change would be:
(abs(340-120) + abs(1250-230) + abs(850-340)+ abs(650-0) + abs(650-0) + abs(1065-0) + abs(200-0) + abs(1465-0) + abs(2000-0)) = 7780. 
As Dell, Yahoo, Verizon, Vodafone, Blackberry, AT&T are new and not there the day before the calculation is simple sales minus 0 (as they were not there the day before so measuring the absolute change).

For **1/3/2012** (the next date). Calculation would be as such:
abs(1465-1250) + abs(1465-340)+abs(700-2000)+abs(235-1465)+abs(500-20) + abs(0-1065)+abs(0-650)+abs(0-650)-abs(0-850) = 11050
As Microsoft, Dell, Yahoo and Verizon were there the previous date but not current date, it would be 0 - sales for those.

The dataset is big and I am trying to find a a simple code which can do all of this. The data involves stocks which can change drastically, and there can be situations where there are no stocks mutual from one date to the other.

Comment: What happen to Google in 1/2 - `abs(0-230) == 230`. And I have no idea how you get to `11050` on day 3 given your own stated abs-sum is only `7385 ` (fixing the negative and vodafone `abs(500-200)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas you can do:

```
>>> df
           Stock      Sales   Data
1/1/2012   Amazon     120     0.996692
1/1/2012   Apple      230     0.084699
1/1/2012   Microsoft  340     0.141253
1/1/2012   Google     230     0.506264
...
>>> df2 = df.pivot(columns='Stock', values='Sales').fillna(0)
>>> df2
Stock       AT&T  Amazon   Apple  Blackberry   Dell  Google  Microsoft  Verizon  Vodafone  Yahoo
1/1/2012     0.0   120.0   230.0         0.0    0.0   230.0      340.0       0.0       0.0    0.0  
1/2/2012  2000.0   340.0  1250.0      1465.0  650.0     0.0      850.0    1065.0     200.0  650.0  
1/3/2012   700.0  1465.0  1465.0       235.0    0.0     0.0        0.0       0.0     500.0    0.0  
>>> df3 = df2.diff().fillna(df2).abs()
>>> df3
Stock       AT&T  Amazon   Apple  Blackberry   Dell  Google  Microsoft  Verizon  Vodafone  Yahoo  
1/1/2012     0.0   120.0   230.0         0.0    0.0   230.0      340.0       0.0       0.0    0.0  
1/2/2012  2000.0   220.0  1020.0      1465.0  650.0   230.0      510.0    1065.0     200.0  650.0  
1/3/2012  1300.0  1125.0   215.0      1230.0  650.0     0.0      850.0    1065.0     300.0  650.0  
>>> df3.sum(axis=1)
1/1/2012     920.0
1/2/2012    8010.0
1/3/2012    7385.0
dtype: float64
```

Note: I don't get the same results because of mistakes in OP's calculation -
 Google seems to be missing from 1/2 and the calculation was just plain wrong for 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like pseudocode and I haven't tested it but it should more or less something like this:

```
prev_sales = {}
last_sales = {}
last_date = rows[0].date

for row in rows:
    if row.date > last_date:
         res = 0

         for key, value in last_sales.iteritems():
            res += abs(value - prev_sales.get(key, 0))

         print last_date, res

         last_date = row.date
         prev_sales = last_sales
         last_sales = {}

    last_sales[row.stock] += last_sales.get(row.stock, 0)
```

Time complexity is O(number of rows + number of days * number of different firms) which in case when most firms occur each day O(number of rows).